# NoMethodError - undefined method `dry_run' for #<Rpush::Client::ActiveRecord::Gcm::Notification:0x00007f7ae62dd3a0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

NoMethodError - undefined method `dry_run' for #

Rupsh is having issue untracable till now.

NoMethodError - undefined method `dry_run' for #<Rpush::Client::ActiveRecord::Gcm::Notification:0x00007f7ae62dd3a0>:
      app/controllers/mobile_controller.rb:89:in`push_notification'
      app/controllers/mobile/prospect_quotes_controller.rb:189:in `notify'
      app/controllers/mobile/prospect_quotes_controller.rb:69:in`accept'

Started POST "/__better_errors/e5b004de0db67afb/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-10-03 14:53:45 +0530

The code:

```
# Android push notification
n = Rpush::Gcm::Notification.new
n.app = Rpush::Gcm::App.find_by_name("android_app")
n.registration_ids = user.device_tokens.pluck(:token)
n.data = { message: message, title: title, body: body }
n.priority = 'high'        # Optional, can be either 'normal' or 'high'
n.content_available = true # Optional
n.save
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, migration in pending on server (it failed to find column)

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed the version of your rpush?

Rerun:

```
$ bundle
$ bundle exec rpush init
$ rails db:migrate
```